# PCI card Legacy mode memory mapping issue

Tags: serial-port, linux-device-driver, vmware, pci

- Using VMWare esxi, I'm developing serial device driver of PCI card which is like 8250 relatd driver in Linux.But i'm using VMware ESxi.
- Firstly I was using PCI card in Enhanced mode.At that time during **pci_iomap(dev,0,5)** where dev is (struct pci_dev *dev).At that time it was returning same **Class and revision id** as i got from configuration space address.
- But when using same card In Legacy mode.Its not returning desire data.
- In **legacy mode** operation card is iomapped and in **Enhanced mode** card is in memory map.
  Please help me to find exact reason.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: VMware doesn't sound for me as an OS.

Comment: Yes.Its my mistake. its Hypervisor.  VMware vSphere Hypervisor is based on VMware ESXi. Thats what in use.

Comment: In Legacy mode PCI card works in IO mapped and in Enhanced mode works in Memory mapped IO. I need to know ,in Legacy mode from where its reading values when i use **pci_iomap** function.

Comment: pci_iomap maps IO or IOMEM resource from PCI BAR0. If the resource is IO the mapping will be done for the low range of ports (0—65535 for generic case).